# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log (n\sin\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log (n\sin\frac{1}{n})$

First, we have
$$   n \sin \frac{1}{n} = \frac{\sin \frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}} < 1 $$
for all positive integers $n$. (Since $\frac{\sin x}{x} < 1 \forall x > 0$.) Therefore,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left| \log \left( n \sin \frac{1}{n} \right)\right| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}-\log  \left( n \sin \frac{1}{n} \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log \left( \frac{1}{n \sin \frac{1}{n}} \right). $$

\begin{align*}  \sin \frac{1}{n} &= \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{6n^3} + \cdots \\[9pt]  \implies n \sin \frac{1}{n} &= 1 - \frac{1}{6n^2} + \cdots \\[9pt]  &\geq 1 - \frac{1}{6n^2} \\[9pt]  &\geq 1 - \frac{1}{n^2}. \end{align*}

Could someone please guide me on how to proceed from here?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: See that : $1 - \dfrac{1}{3! n^2} \leq n \sin \dfrac{1}{n} \leq 1-\dfrac{1}{3! n^2}+\dfrac{1}{5! n^4}$ and $\displaystyle\sum \log\left(  1-\dfrac{1}{3! n^2}+\dfrac{1}{5! n^4} \right)$ is **convergent**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$\sin \frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{6n^3} + O\left(\frac1{n^5}\right)$$

$$n\sin \frac{1}{n} = 1 - \frac{1}{6n^2} + O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)$$

$$\log \left(n \sin \frac {1}{n}\right)=\log \left( 1 - \frac{1}{6n^2} + O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)=-\frac1{6n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)$$

therefore the given series converges by limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: How you deduce that ?

Comment: @LAGRIDA As mentioned we can conclude by LCT since $$\frac{\log \left(n \sin \frac {1}{n}\right)}{-\frac1{n^2}}=\frac16$$ Are you aware about LCT?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Could you please only point out how you were able to obtain : $$\log \left(n \sin \frac {1}{n}\right)\sim \log \left(1-\frac {1}{6n^2}\right)$$

Comment: @MathMan More precisely $$\sin \frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{6n^3} + O(1/n^5)$$ then since as $x \to 0$ $\log (1+x) = x+O(x^2)$ we have $$ \log \left(n \sin \frac {1}{n}\right)=\log \left(1 - \frac{1}{6n^2} + O(1/n^4) \right)=- \frac{1}{6n^2}+O(1/n^4)$$

Comment: I think the comparator should be $\frac {1}{n^3}$. Could you please confirm?

Comment: @MathMan I confirm $1/n^2$ or any other $1/n^a$ with $1<a\le 2$. you can check by your self that by $1/n^3$ we can't conlude by LCT. As suggested, as an alternative we can also refer to direct comparison test using $\log (1+x)\le x$.

Comment: $\sin \dfrac{1}{n} = \dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{3! n^3} + o\left(\dfrac{1}{n^3}\right)$, then :
$$\log\left( n \sin \dfrac{1}{n} \right) = \log\left( 1-\dfrac{1}{3! n^2} + o\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right) \right) = -\dfrac{1}{3! n^2} + o\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: @LAGRIDA I agree! that's exactly what I wrote here but using big O notation. Sorry but I can't see what is your point.

Comment: @gimusi Thanks a lot for your answer. I think i get it now. I am a bit surprised by the down votes though. Your answer seems perfect to me

Comment: @MathMan You are welcome! I'm happy if my help has been useful to you. Don't worry for downvotes, I'm used to that! I've some fond serial downvoters :)

Comment: @gimusi This answer is perfectly fine. Don't hesitate to get in touch with the mods, the serial downvoting will be inspected.

Comment: @GabrielRomon I prefer to ignore the issue, sometimes the serial downvotes are reversed automatically sometimes they aren't. It's really a minor issue for me. Of course sometimes it can be misleading for the readers or also for me to detect the real errors. Thanks a lot for your confirmation. Bye

Answer (score 1):

We have $\sin \dfrac{1}{n} = \dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{3! n^3} + o\left(\dfrac{1}{n^3}\right)$, then :
$$\log\left( n \sin \dfrac{1}{n} \right) = \log\left( 1-\dfrac{1}{3! n^2} + o\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right) \right) = -\dfrac{1}{3! n^2} + o\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right) + \mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^4} \right)$$

Then : 
$$\log\left( n \sin \dfrac{1}{n} \right) = \left(-\dfrac{1}{6}+o(1)\right) \dfrac{1}{n^2}+ \mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

Then: 
$$n \to +\infty, \log\left( n \sin \dfrac{1}{n} \right) \sim \dfrac{-1}{6n^2}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer !

Comment: I am a bit new to the o-notation. I do know that it means, but unable to comprehend how you deduced those relations. Could you explain a bit more in detail? thanks a lot

Comment: @MathMan can you specify wich line ?

Comment: The first line itself. thanks

Comment: $$x \to 0, \sin(x)=x - \dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots+(-1)^n \dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}+o(x^{2n+1})$$